# How to log request / response bodies in warp?

Tags: logging, rust, rust-warp

I am trying to log request / response bodies in warp.

When using `warp::log::custom`, the `Info` struct doesn't contain any info about it.

When trying to implement my own log wrapper, based on the implementation of `warp::log`, the `Route` struct is private (among others).

I can log bodies after they are deserialized using

```rust
warp::body::json().map(|it| {
    println!("Hello : {:?}", it);
    it
})
```

But if the user doesn't send a correct body, it wont work. Moreover, I am looking for a simple way to log all requests bodies.

Answer (score 8):

I have stumbled upon this while searching for the solution myself so maybe it will be useful for someone in the future.

You can use `warp::body::bytes()` to get body not necessarily in json format:

```
warp::body::bytes()
    .map(|b: Bytes| {
        println!("Request body: {}", std::str::from_utf8(b.bytes()).expect("error converting bytes to &str"));

        "Hello, World!"
    }
```

To make it more universal I have managed to make a function which I can use in my filters easily:

```
fn log_body() -> impl Filter<Extract = (), Error = Rejection> + Copy {
    warp::body::bytes()
        .map(|b: Bytes| {
            println!("Request body: {}", std::str::from_utf8(b.bytes()).expect("error converting bytes to &str"));
        })
        .untuple_one()
}
```

It can be then used as such:

```
    let api = warp::any()
        .and(log_body())
        .and_then(handle);
```

For a full example, you can check out [the gist I have prepared.](https://gist.github.com/Szymongib/7d9ab3318e3c30cf231963d083d30d7d)

Comment: @nbari That will be something like this https://gist.github.com/Szymongib/c051c56e8eba8f6464a448e809c370c0

Comment: 2023, b.bytes() seems to work no more. To fix this you need to run  map on bytes like this:

.map(|b: Bytes| {
          let v =  b.to_vec();
          let c = &*v;
          println!("Request body: {}", std::str::from_utf8(c).expect("error converting bytes to &str")); 
      })
      .untuple_one()